# Python's timedelta: can't I just get in whatever time unit I want the value of the entire difference?

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

I am trying to have some clever dates since a post has been made on my site ("seconds since, hours since, weeks since, etc..") and I'm using datetime.timedelta difference between utcnow and utc dated stored in the database for a post.

Looks like, according to the docs, I have to use the days attribute AND the seconds attribute, to get the fancy date strings I want.

Can't I just get in whatever time unit I want the value of the entire difference? Am I missing something?

It would be perfect if I could just get the entire difference in seconds.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It seems that Python 2.7 has introduced a [total_seconds()](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds) method, which is what you were looking for, I believe!

Answer (score 15):

You can compute the difference in seconds.

```
total_seconds = delta.days * 86400 + delta.seconds
```

No, you're no "missing something".  It doesn't provide deltas in seconds.

Comment: That's what I plan on doing, but I just didn't want that kludge in my code if there was something I didn't know about. Thanks.

Comment: This approach, like `total_seconds()` in Python 2.7, will return an incorrect result if the days don't have 24 hours (for example, because of changes in daylight saving time).

Comment: I have to agree with Bruno - this will give wrong results twice a year, so it's not a correct answer.

Comment: The correct value is "(td.microseconds + (td.seconds + td.days * 24 * 3600) * 10**6) / 10**6". (for python versions less than 2.7 that can't use total_seconds)

Comment: @markwatson it is not exactly the same total_seconds(). Looks like it is truncating the milliseconds... Thanks anyway! :-)

Answer (score 5):

> It would be perfect if I could just get the entire difference in seconds.

Then plain-old-unix-timestamp as provided by the 'time' module may be more to your taste.

I personally have yet to be convinced by a lot of what's in 'datetime'.

Comment: +1 for suggesting a solution that doesn't assume that all days have 24 hours.

Answer (score 5):

Like bobince said, you could use timestamps, like this:

```
# assuming ts1 and ts2 are the two datetime objects
from time import mktime
mktime(ts1.timetuple()) - mktime(ts2.timetuple())
```

Although I would think this is even uglier than just calculating the seconds from the `timedelta` object...

Comment: You can further complicate things: `reduce(float.__sub__, (mktime(d.utctimetuple()) for d in (ts1, ts2)))`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: but why?

Comment: What will happen if ts1 is in one time zone and ts2 is in another? Or, they're in the same timezone but one is in Daylight Saving time and the other is not?