# Converting date into hours

Tags: python, datetime, hour

I want to find time difference between two date and then compare the difference time in hours. Something like this,

StartTime =  2011-03-10 15:45:48
EndTime =  2011-03-10 18:04:00

And then find the difference as,
 timeDifference = abs(StartTime - EndTime)
And then I need to compare the results as,
If timeDifference > 6 hours 
 ...

When I use this method, the results I got was is in time format, how should I change time format into hours in python?

Thank you,

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let's assume that you have your two dates and times as `datetime` objects (see [datetime.datetime](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects)):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> start_time = datetime.datetime(2011,3,10,15,45,48)
>>> end_time = datetime.datetime(2011,3,10,18,4,0)
```

Subtracting one `datetime` from another gives you a `timedelta` object, and you can use `abs` to ensure the time difference is positive:

```
>>> start_time - end_time
datetime.timedelta(-1, 78108)
>>> abs(start_time - end_time)
datetime.timedelta(0, 8292)
```

Now, to convert the seconds difference from a timedelta into hours, just divide by 3600:

```
>>> hours_difference = abs(start_time - end_time).total_seconds() / 3600.0
>>> hours_difference
2.3033333333333332
```

Note that the `total_seconds()` method was introduced in Python 2.7, so if you want that on an earlier version, you'll need to calculate it yourself from `.days` and `.seconds` as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500168/pythons-timedelta-cant-i-just-get-in-whatever-time-unit-i-want-the-value-of-th/500195#500195)

*Update:* [Jochen Ritzel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/95612/jochen-ritzel) points out in a comment below that if it's just the comparison with a number of hours that you're interested in, rather that the raw value, you can do that more easily with:

```
abs(start_time - end_time) > timedelta(hours=6)
```

Comment: to check if the difference is more than 6 hours you can just do `abs(start_time - end_time) > timedelta(hours=6)`.

Comment: @Jochen Ritzel: good point, thanks - I've updated my answer to mention that.