# Python - Time delta from string and now()

Tags: python, datetime

I have spent some time trying to figure out how to get a time delta between time values. The only issue is that one of the times was stored in a file. So I have one string which is in essence `str(datetime.datetime.now())` and `datetime.datetime.now()`.

Specifically, I am having issues getting a delta because one of the objects is a datetime object and the other is a string.

I think the answer is that I need to get the string back in a datetime object for the delta to work.

I have looked at some of the other Stack Overflow questions relating to this including the following:

[Python - Date & Time Comparison using timestamps, timedelta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12131766/python-date-time-comparison-using-timestamps-timedelta)
[Comparing a time delta in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591845/comparing-a-time-delta-in-python)
[Convert string into datetime.time object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14295673/convert-string-into-datetime-time-object)
[Converting string into datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime)

Example code is as follows:

```
f = open('date.txt', 'r+')
line = f.readline()
date = line[:26]
now = datetime.datetime.now()   
then = time.strptime(date)
delta = now - then # This does not work
```

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

For reference, the first 26 characters are acquired from the first line of the file because this is how I am storing time e.g.

```
f.write(str(datetime.datetime.now())
```

Which would write the following:
2014-01-05 13:09:42.348000

Comment: Thanks to all that responded. Problem solved, thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`time.strptime` returns a struct_time.
`datetime.datetime.now()` returns a `datetime` object.
The two can not be subtracted directly.

Instead of `time.strptime` you could use `datetime.datetime.strptime`, which returns a `datetime` object. Then you could subtract `now` and `then`.

For example,

```
import datetime as DT
now = DT.datetime.now()   
then = DT.datetime.strptime('2014-1-2', '%Y-%m-%d')
delta = now - then 
print(delta)
# 3 days, 8:17:14.428035
```

---

By the way, you need to supply a date format string to `time.strptime` or `DT.datetime.strptime`.

```
time.strptime(date)
```

should have raised a ValueError.

---

It looks like your date string is 26 characters long. That might mean you have a date string like  `'Fri, 10 Jun 2011 11:04:17 '`.

If that is true, you may want to parse it like this:

```
then = DT.datetime.strptime('Fri, 10 Jun 2011 11:04:17 '.strip(), "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S")
print(then)
# 2011-06-10 11:04:17
```

There is a table describing the available directives (like `%Y`, `%m`, etc.) [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

Comment: Thanks for the actual explanation on where I went wrong as well. It helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import time
import datetime
d = datetime.datetime.now()
now  = time.mktime(d.timetuple())
```

And then apply the delta

Answer (score 0):

if you have the year,month,day of 'then' you may use:

```
year  = 2013
month = 1
day   = 1

now_date = datetime.datetime.now()
then_date = now_date.replace(year = year, month = month, day = day)

delta = now_date - then_date
```