# Find time difference between 2 time stamp values in python

Tags: python, timestamp

```
import datetime

def get_time_value(timestamp):
     time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
     return time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

I have

```
start_time = 1518842893.04001
end_time = 1518842898.21265

get_time_value(end_time-start_time)
```

It gives

```
1969-12-31 16:00:05
```

and not the correct value

```
'startTime': '2018-02-16 20:48:13', 'endTime': '2018-02-16 20:48:18'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate the time interval between two time strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096953/how-to-calculate-the-time-interval-between-two-time-strings)

Comment: Your 'correct value' looks like a dictionary containing the start and end times but without curly-braces.  Is this really what you want?  The title of the post says that you want the time difference between the 2 time stamp values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - Date & Time Comparison using timestamps, timedelta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12131766/python-date-time-comparison-using-timestamps-timedelta)

Answer (score 1):

To get the time difference between two timestamps, first convert them to `datetime` objects before the subtraction.  If you do this then the result will be a `datetime.timedelta` object.  Once you have a `datetime.timedelta` object you can convert it to seconds or however you want to display the time difference.

For example.

```
time1 = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(start_time)
time2 = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(end_time)
time_difference = time2 - time1
print(time_difference)
```

Output:

```
0:00:05.172640
```

Or:

```
print(time_difference.total_seconds())
```

Output:

```
5.17264
```

Comment: And how is that any better than just doing `end_time-start_time`?  This is just a pointless conversion into datetime instances and then back again.

Comment: Good point.  I admit I still don't know what you mean by "Find time difference between 2 time stamp values in python"  Can you show the output you want to produce?